# VS 2012 P4SCC automatic check out doesn't work

Tags: version-control, visual-studio-2012, perforce

Has anyone used the old P4SCC plugin with VS 2012, and stumbled upon automatic check out not working? If so, have you resolved it?

I've made sure that the source control is up and running and that in Tools-Options-Source Control-Environment-On Save the "Check out automatically" is selected.

Still, every time I save a modified file, it shows the Save As dialog. Frustrating...

Comment: Perforce has a new plugin for Visual Studio.  Might be worth a try particularly with VS 2012.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it's related to your specific problem, but my automatic check out failed as well the same way you describe (with TFS without P4SCC).

In my case, the problem was that the solution happen to be offline. Right-click on the solution name (at Solution Explorer) -> "Go Online" and the issue was resolved!